# How to do data augmentation in Stylegan2 model training?

Tags: generative-adversarial-network, data-augmentation

Sorry for a newbie question.
How exactly to do data augmentation (by another dataset/model) while training a Stylegan2 model? As an example, when a dataset of faces is applied in training of a model for full body pictures, to improve faces here. Another example is on the screenshot.
[image: Data augmentation]
There is some script file for it, or I need to add some argument for training command?
(Seriously, no specific info in readme.md or anywhere, and in Google too)

Comment: Data augmentation isn't like, a checkbox step in model training -- it's a whole field of study. There are many approaches to data augmentation used out in the wild, you'll need to either select one or check the project's references to see which they used (I've never heard of PALM and nothing turns up in search)

Comment: The required type of data augmentation is to refine specific details by applying of a separated dataset. PALM is a dataset of hands, cropped from character images.